# What are the honorary titles assigned by Asimov to various generic people?

Tags: isaac-asimov

In non-fiction works, including introductions to fiction, Isaac Asimov often gave titles to  people in certain positions, such as "the Gentle Reader", "the Noble Printer", and "the Kindly Editor".

Is there a more complete list of similar expressions that the "Good Doctor" used?

Comment: "Gentle reader" is much older than Asimov.

Comment: @Mary, yes, going as far back as at least Charlotte Brontë.